# Ionic 3: Gradient background

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

It is easy to change the background color of an Ionic App by setting `$background-color` in `variables.scss`, but it wont work with gradients or images. I was surprised that I could not find any official documentation on this, nor a lot of useful questions and answers.

If you set `$background-color` to a non-color you will currently get a Sass error from one of the many Ionic components that calculate their colors based on the background color.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So here is what I ended up doing, first in `src/theme/variables.scss`:

```
$app-background: linear-gradient(to bottom, color($colors, light) 0%, color($colors, dark) 100%);
$background-color: transparent;
$toolbar-background: transparent;
```

The normal background and toolbar must be transparent to show the gradient underneath. We apply the gradient in `src/app/app.scss`:

```
ion-content {
    background: $app-background;
}
```

You may think that `ion-content` only takes up the space between your header/navbar and footer/tabs, but is actually styled by Ionic to fill the entire screen. So you got your gradient from top to bottom. **Success**.